# MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() not filling MySqlParameter(s)

Tags: c#, mysql

Background: I am rewriting my ASP.NET application - currently it uses MS SQL database but I need to support also MySQL (both in the same time!).

Most of work is done - I used **MySQL Connector/Net** for work with MySQL database from C# (Visual Studio 2010) - but I have troubles with certain SQL queries. This is SQL query I need to execute:

```
"SELECT @username=username FROM t_Users WHERE id=@id"
```

Here is my code:

```
public static int ExecuteSqlNonQuery(string i_szQuery)
{
    bool bConnectionWasOpen = false;
    AbstractConnection dbConnection = CMSSQLInstanceCreator.CreateConnection();            

    if(dbConnection.IsMySQL())
    {
        MySqlConnection aSqlConnection = dbConnection.GetMysConnection();
        try
        {
            if (aSqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                aSqlConnection.Open();
            else
                if (aSqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    bConnectionWasOpen = true;
                else
                    throw new ApplicationException("Connection not available!");

            List<MySqlParameter> aParameters1 = new List<MySqlParameter>();
            aParameters1.Add(new MySqlParameter("@username", MySqlDbType.VarString, 128));
            aParameters1.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32));
            aParameters1[0].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;                
            aParameters1[1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            aParameters1[1].Value = (int)1;

            MySqlCommand aSqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(i_szQuery, aSqlConnection);
            aSqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            aSqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            aSqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            aSqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(aParameters1.ToArray());

            int iResult = aSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(iResult <= 0)
                Debug.WriteLine("aResult <= 0: " + i_szQuery);
            return iResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Cannot execute query!\nReason: '" + ex.Message + "'", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!bConnectionWasOpen && aSqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                aSqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
      //... almost the same for MS SQL
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Output parameter **@username** (System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;) is not filled with the value from query.

If I use other query - e.g.

```
UPDATE t_Users SET password=@new_password WHERE (password=@old_password AND id=@user)
```

Everything is fine.

I cannot return scalar as there are many other queries like

```
SELECT @username=username, @is_blocked=is_blocked, @full_name=full_name, @must_change_pwd=must_change_pwd ...
```

returning many values and I do not want to rewrite most of code.

It looks like there is problem only in MySQL because the same code works with MS SQL fine.

What should I use to force MySqlParameter to load the value from query?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the value of the output like this

```
aSqlCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

It apparently is a shortcoming in the MySql .Net connector, see [#75267](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75267). Tested it with connector v6.9.7 and MySql server 5.5.45. It is still broken and the bug report - of december 2014 - is still open. Output parameters work for stored procedures, with a command type StoredProcedure, and do not work for a SELECT statement that assigns output parameters as part of the select; command type Text.

2023-02-16 Update. A couple of weeks ago it is fixed in version 8.0.32. I tested it by updating Connector/NET to 8.0.32, and by using NuGet package MySql.Data 8.0.32.

A command of type text, an output parameter and an ExecuteNonQuery now works for the following case:

```
SET @valNum:=(SELECT ValueNumber FROM `sky.application` WHERE Name='Agents')
```

Value @valNum can then be retrieved through the output parameter.

Note that retrieving two values does not work as follows, despite it does the job in the Workbench:

```
SELECT @valNum:=ValueNumber, @instNum:=InstanceNumber FROM `sky.application` WHERE Name='Agents'
```

Error: Parameter 'valNum:=ValueNumber' not found in the collection.
Same error if retrieving one value.

Fortunately the following syntax works:

```
SELECT ValueNumber, InstanceNumber INTO @valNum, @instNum FROM `sky.application` WHERE Name='Agents'
```